A combinatorial equation
I want to show that
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}(-1)^i\binom{n-k}{i}(n-k-i)^{n-2}=n^{n-2},
$$
for $n\geq 3.$
Background: I was asked to calculate the number of labeled trees on $[n]$ with exactly $k$ leaves. We discussed the Prufer code in class and here is my calculation.
A number appears in the code if and only if this vertex is not a leaf. Hence, this is equal to the number of Prufer codes of length $n-2$ using exactly $n-k$ different numbers. We first choose the number of $k$ leaves and discard them. Then the term $$\binom{n-k}{i}(n-k-i)^{n-2}$$ gives the number of codes using no more than $n-k-i$ numbers. The rest follows from the inclusion-exclusion principle. In conclusion, $$\binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}(-1)^i\binom{n-k}{i}(n-k-i)^{n-2}$$ is the number of trees with exactly $k$ leaves.
Furthermore, I would like to check that this calculation goes through with Cayley's formula. And this gives the equation I wrote at the very beginning.

Did you try to compute any value given by your formula? It produces $0$ for $n = 1, 2, 3$, and $12$ for $n = 4$, and $120$ for $n = 5$.
An obvious problem is limiting $k$ by $n - 2$ while tree may have $n - 1$ leaves. It fixes cases $n = 3, 4, 5$. And cases $n = 1, 2$ could be defined as special.

@Smylic The case $n=1$ should be excluded at first. The case $n=2$ can be fixed by allowing $k=n$ in the summation and assume $0^0=1$. For $n\geq 3$, a tree on $n$ vertices will have at most $n-1$ leaves. I admit that was a typo... Thanks!

For the count of trees with $k$ leaves we need to count
Pruefer sequences of length $n-2$ where the $n-k$ nodes
that are not leaves appear  at least once.  This may be
done using Stirling  numbers but OP asks  for PIE. With
the PIE  poset the nodes $Q$  where $Q$ is a  subset of
the $n-k$ vertices /  labels represent codes where some
subset  of $Q$  appears.  The  weight on  the nodes  is
$(-1)^{n-k-|Q|}$  and  the  poset  is  ordered  by  set
inclusion.   Now  Pruefer  sequences  where  all  $n-k$
values are  present appear only in  $Q=[n-k]$ and hence
contribute with  total weight one. All  other sequences
where  $P\subset  [n-k]$  different values  appear  are
represented at all  $Q$ that are supersets  of $P$ with
total weight
$$\sum_{P\subseteq Q \subseteq [n-k]} (-1)^{n-k-|Q|}
= \sum_{q=0}^{n-k-|P|}
{n-k-|P|\choose q} (-1)^{n-k-|P|-q} = 0.$$
This is zero as required. On the other hand counting by
the  cardinality of  the sequences  represented at  $Q$
which is $|Q|^{n-2}$ we get
$$\sum_{Q\subseteq [n-k]} (-1)^{n-k-|Q|} |Q|^{n-2}
= \sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n-k\choose q} (-1)^{n-k-q} q^{n-2}.$$
Summing  over all  possible  counts $k$  of leaves  and
restoring the chooser in front we find
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} {n\choose k} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n-k\choose q} (-1)^{n-k-q} q^{n-2}.$$
Next we  continue with the sequence  of simplifications
starting with the inner sum
$$(n-2)! [w^{n-2}] \sum_{q=0}^{n-k} 
{n-k\choose q} (-1)^{n-k-q} \exp(qw)
\\ = (n-2)! [w^{n-2}] (\exp(w)-1)^{n-k}.$$
This  is  the  ordered   Stirling  set  number  $(n-k)!
{n-2\brace  n-k}$.   Note  that   $(\exp(w)-1)^{n-k}  =
w^{n-k}+\cdots.$   Working  with   the  outer   sum  we
therefore  get  a  zero  contribution  when  $k=0$  and
$k=1$. We  also get zero  when $k=n.$ (Here  we suppose
$n\ge 3$.) This leaves
$$(n-2)! [w^{n-2}]
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (\exp(w)-1)^{n-k}
= (n-2)! [w^{n-2}] \exp(nw) = n^{n-2}$$
and we have our claim.
